Comparing calculated DOS with experimental valence band spectra for oxidized platinum nanoparticles
I've been studying the electronic structure of platinum nanoparticles using DFT and have a question about comparing my calculated density of states (DOS) with experimental valence band spectra.
I recently came across a paper (Phys.Chem.Chem.Phys., 2017, 19, 6013) that investigates the oxidation states of platinum nanoparticles of similar sizes using near ambient pressure hard X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (NAP-HAXPES). The authors observed a decrease in the density of electronic states near the Fermi energy for smaller platinum nanoparticles at higher voltages, which they attributed to the oxidation of the nanoparticles.
However, when I calculated the DOS for a model system (cluster in vacuum, this is DFT) of platinum nanoparticles with varying oxygen ratios, I found an important increase in the density of states around the same energy range as the oxygen ratio increased.
I am not an experimentalist, and while I am aware about thousands of reasons why experiments would give different results in practice, I am wondering if one is even able to compare these two graphs in theory. It is my understanding that the intensity from the NAP-HAXPES measurement should be proportional to the Density of State?

If I understood correctly, the experimental oxidation is due to both applied voltage and oxygen. Is this the same in your calculations?

@PaulKolk No, my calculations are oxidized platinum nanoparticle centered in a vacuum box, this is very far from any kind of electrochemical setup, mainly every electric effects due to charge screening will be missing, etc... This is a kind of explanation that I aim to provide in my manuscript, but first I would like to know if these two graphs are even comparable in principle.

Oxidation by oxygen is one effect, interaction with oxide ions is another. As you provide more oxide ions in your theory than really present, the result is expected to differ a lot.

@PaulKolk Mmmh, I am not sure that I understand your point, in the calculations oxygen atoms are partially charged not pure ions, do you mean that because of the lack of charge effects, they will be wrong?

For a given oxidation state of the platinum cluster, the number of oxygen atoms changes the densities of states, I think. Even if they are not 2- ions.
